# Is start Intent replaced when starting a SingleInstance Activity with a new Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a SingleInstance Activity that I start with StartActivity(Intent);

Once started I would like to occassionally update it (the already started activity) with a new Intent containing new data.

The question I have is: Can I call startActivity([a new intent here]) and receive that new Intent
in the activity? It seems it is possible (kindof) with singleTop's onNewIntent(Intent), but what about SingleInstance? I can't seem to get a straight answer about this case...

Otherwise how would I do?

In short:
If I do startActivity(Intent) repeatedly with different Intents, does getIntent() reflect the new Intents used in startactivity?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see if it works? It is  a 5 minute exercise to make a simple test program to test this.

Comment: Yeah, well, I don't think you will find anyone interested in investing time answering your question if you won't invest 5 minutes in it yourself. Good luck!

Comment: Ridiculous attitude because sometimes I have time to answer other peoples questions and sometimes I have not. Sometimes other people have time and sometimes they do not. When people have or not is not in sync. Answering other peoples questions when having time makes everyone benefit in the long run. Right now I have too much on my plate so I threw out a question, thinking maybe someone knew right away without experimenting. Next time when you dont have time and I do, I wont answer your question.

Comment: Furthermore: It might be a 5 min (probably more) exercise to see that it works 92 times out of a 100, but it is not a 5 min exercise to verify that something always behaves exactly the same way under all circumstances. I would like my answers to be based on knowledge and not trial-and-error whenever possible.